# How to open a PhpStorm project without PhpStorm

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, phpstorm

I had to make a School Project and decided to make one with PhpStorm and Laravel. My teacher doesn't have PhpStorm and told me to find a way so he could open it.

Is there any possibility to open a PhpStorm/Laravel without PhpStorm?

Comment: You can open it in any IDE / Text Editor, I mean it's just a bunch of folders with files inside them! You can use Visual Code it's free or Atom (which is also free)

Comment: You can open project in any `IDE`. Project does not required any `specific IDE`

Comment: A project is just a directory with subdirectories and files. Only the difference is that the IDEs are setting own configuration files like .idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are still there, you can use any IDE or even Text Editor to view the files.

The only thing PHPStorm adds to your project is a folder called `.idea` which is used for configurations on PhpStorm, and your teached doesn't need it

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers!! Could you please also tell me which file i have to open in IDE?

Comment: The project folder. For example if you have your project in `/var/www/myProject` you should open the folder `myProject` to see the Laravel files

Comment: Thank you really much!! I know that maybe I'm annoying you, but could you please tell me how I can see the Project. Does it go with localhost?

Comment: You will need a local web server or use artisan, inside your project folder execute `php artisan serve` and you will see your project in `localhost:8000`. But try to learn something about local web servers or Laravel Homestead